# Multiple string replace at one time

Tags: vb.net

I have this string abcd, and I want to replace the a with [a|b] and the b with [c|d]

I try many ways to do it, like

```
        Dim varString As String = "abcd"
        varString = varString.Replace("a", "[a|b]")
        varString = varString.Replace("b", "[c|d]")
```

***The result I get is***

[a|[c|d]][c|d]cd

***Instead I want it like this***

[a|b][c|d]cd

The problem is every time I use the replace function it backs to change the values I already replaced before so I replaced a with [a|b] but then when I do my second command to replace the b it changes the b in [a|b] that I just changed and I don't want this.

I tried to use StringBuilder but it gives the same result.

Please advise me,

Comment: Are all the string to be replaced single characters? If yes, it could be better to just loop all characters one by one.

Comment: Yes, this what I'm trying to do now

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by making an array in this way

```
        Dim NewCommand As String = "abcd"
        For i = 0 To LikeCommand.Length - 1
            If LikeCommand(i) = "a" Then
                NewCommand += "[a|b]"
            ElseIf LikeCommand(i) = "b" Then
                NewCommand += "[c|d]"
            Else
                NewCommand += LikeCommand(i)
            End If
        Next
        LikeCommand = NewCommand
```

Answer (score 0):

Or just switch the logic up.  But obviously I'm thinking you're using a basic example for a more complex question.

```
dim varString as string = "abcd"
varString = varString.Replace("b" ,"[c|d]")
varString = varString.Replace("a" ,"[a|b]")
```

That would get you the desired results.